# ¿Cómo poner en producción una app de Angular2 con Apache?

Tags: angularjs, apache

Quiero publicar en un servidor de pruebas el build de mi aplicación utilizando Apache.

De esta manera genero el build `$ ng build --prod` y me genera el directorio `dist`.

Tengo un directorio en mi servidor dentro de `/var/www/miapp.com/public_html` donde subí el contenido de `dist`. Y tengo un VirtualHost con lo siquiente:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/miapp.com/public_html

    ServerName miapp.com
    ServerAlias www.miapp.com

    <Directory /var/www/miapp.com/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Esto me funciona y la aplicación abre el index.html al entrar a miapp.com, tengo un menu para desplazarme a más secciones como `/noticias` o `/galeria` que funcionan con `routerLink` funcionan al darles click y te llevan al componente correspondiente.

Mi problema es que si estoy, por ejemplo, en la `miapp.com/noticias` y recargo la página con `Ctrl+R` o similar, me tira el siguiente error:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /noticias was not found on this server.
```

[He visto que puedo sustituir el VirtualHost por un archivo `.htaccess`como el siguiente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41348210/how-to-configure-apache-for-angular-2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Pero tengo el mismo problema.

Comment: faltaría activar el htaccess o mover las rules al <directory> del virtualhost

Comment: Quitaste de tu ruta el `#` o por que no lo usas? Intenta usar `miapp.com/#/noticias`.

Answer (score 2):

prueba cambiando el virtual host en la seccion directory para agregarle indexes

```
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
```

luego restart el apache y te debería tomar el .htaccess

Así debería quedar el virtualhost (edit: agregué RewriteEngine On)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/miapp.com/public_html

    ServerName miapp.com
    ServerAlias www.miapp.com

    <Directory /var/www/miapp.com/public_html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

editar, reiniciar apache y ver que pasa, si no toma los rewrites podemos activar el log para ver que está haciendo el modulo de apache.

Comment: Gracias por responder. Intenté con y sin `.htaccess` pero no funcionó.

Comment: Sí, tal cual lo copié y pegué.