# Problema de rutas con Angular y servicios web con PHP

Tags: php, angular, angular8, angular-router

Al subir el proyecto de angular a producción aparentemente el "routerLink" funciona bien al momento de ir de una ruta a otra, pero si recargo la página o quiero modificar directamente la URL para navegar a una ruta en especifico, aparece "Not Found", tal como adjunto en la imagen, ¿Por qué puede pasar esto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: seguramente necesites redireccionar el errordocument al index ( asi el posible 404 lo procesa angular ) que servidor web usas? nginx, apache, etc?

Comment: Utilizo apache, en donde podría configurar eso?

Comment: en el virtual host o en un .htaccess, en esta pregunta están ambas formas : https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/152415/81450 ( una forma mas completa en SO en https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740184/1423096 ) las reglas son si es un archivo o un directorio dejarlo pasar sino darselo a index.html para que el script lo maneje

Comment: @aloMalbarez Muchas gracias.